# Как запустить тесты на селенид удаленно?

Tags: java, spring, maven, непрерывная-интеграция, selenide

Скажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина. Локально тесты отлично отрабатывают. При запуске в GitLab ci/cd ошибка COUD NOT START A NEW SESSION. Response code 500. Chrome failed to start: expired normally

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.